# MySql query find closest color, passing in RGB values

Tags: mysql, colors, rgb

I'm working on a system in which you can search and order products by their colors. I have a query for this today but it's pretty slow when there are many products in the set. Does anyone have a solution to make it more effective?

The tables:

```
* = index
**products**
+------------+----------+
| id_product*| id_image*|
+------------+----------+
|     1      |   5      |
|     2      |   8      |
|     3      |   3      |
|     4      |   9      |
|     5      |   2      |
|     ...... |   ...... |
+------------+----------+
// and some more product data, only these columns used in this query

**image_rgb**
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| id_image*| id_rgb_color*| dominance   |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
|    23016 |          242 | 0.119562465 |
|   590855 |           16 | 0.042380076 |
|   605196 |            1 | 0.062330416 |
|     8436 |          146 | 0.063439071 |
|    68452 |           30 | 0.103740936 |
|    ..... |        ..... | ........... |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
// dominance not in use for now, havent't figured out a good way to implement this yet

**rgb_colors**
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
| id_rgb*| r*  | g*  | b*  |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|      1 | 240 | 240 | 230 |
|      2 | 230 | 210 | 190 |
|      3 | 230 | 220 | 210 |
|      4 | 220 | 200 | 180 |
|      5 | 250 | 250 | 250 |
|    ... | ... | ... | ... |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+

**product_categories**
+------------+-------------+
| id_product*| id_category*|
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          35 |
|          2 |          15 |
|          3 |           8 |
|          4 |          39 |
|          5 |          61 |
|      ..... |       ..... |
+------------+-------------+
```

The query:

```
$r = 150;
$g = 100;
$b = 170;
$categories = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....';
SELECT a.id_product,
 (SELECT
  min
  (
   ABS(rgb_colors.r - $r) + // passing in red value
   ABS(rgb_colors.g - $g) + // passing in green value
   ABS(rgb_colors.b - $b)   // passing in blue value
  ) clrDiff                 // finding the closest match - 0 is exact match
  FROM image_rgb
  JOIN rgb_colors ON rgb_colors.id_rgb = image_rgb.id_rgb_color
  WHERE image_rgb.id_image = a.id_image
 ) clrDiff
FROM products a
JOIN product_categories b ON b.id_product = a.id_product
WHERE 
product_categories.id_category IN ($categories)
GROUP BY a.id_product
ORDER BY clrDiff DESC
LIMIT 48
OFFSET 0
```

Result:

```
+------------+-------------+
| id_product*| clrDiff     |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          0  |
|          2 |          5  |
|          3 |          8  |
|          4 |          13 |
|          5 |          28 |
|      ..... |       ..... |
+------------+-------------+
```

This query gives a good result but it's slow, takes a few second with about 50.000 products. Have tried a few alternatives but they've been either even slower or not given good enough results.

Comment: 1. Pls post the results of the explain for the above query. 2. Pls share all the indexes and the fields within the indexes for all affected tables.

Comment: We don't perceive 'closeness' amongst reds, blues, and greens in the same way. So there are functions for doing this kind of thing. I'd use one of those.